# How to configure log4j in a unit testing environment?

Tags: java, unit-testing, log4j

What is the best way to configure log4j for use in a unit testing environment? I prefer my unit tests to have no external dependencies, so reading the log4j configuration file is not an option. Ideally there would be 1 or 2 function calls I could make from within the unit test setup function.

Comment: Have you thought of using SLF4J which may be better for your usecase I think.

Comment: External Log4J configuration is not bad, since a developer may change it when hunting bugs.

Answer (score 19):

you could put a static code block at the top of the test that does

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Note that the problem with this is that every time that line is executed, log4j will add an appender and you will get duplicate log statements.  So if you do that in every test class, you will end up with n duplicates of every log statement.

So I recommend creating a class that is your BaseTestCase and doing that in there.

Note, having some sort of test-resources with the relevant configuration is not a bad idea...

Comment: Thank you. The duplicate appenders has been my problem with this approach.

Comment: A simpler way to not "end up with n duplicates of every log statement" is to precede the above code line with: BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();

Answer (score 3):

Log4j is already an external dependency. But anyway, you got your answer below (hvgotcodes), so I'll just add that you can set up log4j programatically. Basically everything you can do via config, you can do by code as well:

http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2007/09/programmatically-configuring-log4j-and.html